# How to draw xlink:href to canvas

Tags: javascript, svg, canvas

I have multiple SVG shapes that I want to render.

I'm currently creating an Image object for each svg separately which leads to many unnecessary HTTP requests.

```
const imageEl = new Image();
imageEl.src = image.src;
// And then
ctx.drawImage(this.image, this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
```

I want to use one sprite file which contains all my SVG'S and draw them to the canvas like in `HTML` using `<use xlink:href="SOME_URL"></use>`

How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

#### A few reminders:

- *It's not clear from your question how exactly you are managing your assets, so I add this as a reminder, but note it it the most important point of this answer:* **You should load all your assets, only once, and before you start using any of these.**
  This means, the `new Image()` call should be made from the app's initialization step, and the `drawImage()` one should be made in the app's drawing step, itself called in the anim' loop.

  ```
  // in 'loadAssets()' called from 'init()' only once  per 'uri'
  const img = new Image();
  img.onload = thisLoaded;
  img.src = uri;

  // in 'draw()' called from 'anim()'
  ctx.drawImage(img, ...
  ```
- Your problem boils down to being able to load these references from an *<img>* element. That is what the Canvas2d API requires as source, and this is actually the biggest culprit here. <sub>(*drawImage* also accepts svg's *<image>* but I don't think it's any relevance here)</sub>
- Most svg elements have no sense taken on their own. All the coordinates we use to define them need to be relative to their viewPort's parent's *viewBox*. So almost no single element can be painted only on their own. If the svg *<use>* element is able to "render" single elements, it is because this very `<use>` element is itself contained in an *<svg>* element, which defines that *viewBox*.
- Images loaded from an *<img>* element can **not** perform any request to external resources.
  This means that dynamically generating multiple simple svg documents only made of `<svg><use href="https://foo.bar#baz"></svg>` won't help us here, *#baz* should be part of the document itself.

---

Now that all this has been cleared up, we can come up with a few solutions:

*In below examples, the [svg image used](https://www.dropbox.com/s/s7aynuqx6pe1we8/fake_use.svg?dl=0) is made of two elements, one with an id of `rect` and the other one with an id of `circle`.*

First one, which may be the most obvious, is to **build your own *<use>* system.**
You could first fetch your spritesheet svg, parse from js, and then generate the svg you need to get drawn by selecting only the elements you want.

But the biggest problem with this method is that svg's can have very complex linkage, and that retrieving all the targeted elements is not an easy task.

So here, I'll only show a basic implementation where we are only able to target direct elements (no *<style>* import, no *url(#...)* etc.). If you really need something complete, let me know I did write something some time ago...

```js
function loadSvgDoc(uri) {
  return fetch(uri)
  .then(r => r.text())
  .then(markup => (new DOMParser())
      .parseFromString(markup, 'image/svg+xml')
  );
}

function loadFakeUse(doc, id) {
  const root = doc.documentElement;
  const node = doc.getElementById(id);
  if(!root || !node)
    return Promise.reject('invalid params');
  const clone =  root.cloneNode();
  clone.append(node);
  const markup = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(clone);
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    const img = new Image();
    img.onload = e => res(img);
    img.onerror = rej;
    img.src = 'data:image/svg+xml,' + encodeURIComponent(markup);
  });
}

loadSvgDoc('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/s7aynuqx6pe1we8/fake_use.svg')
  .then(doc => 
    Promise.all([
      loadFakeUse(doc, 'rect'),
      loadFakeUse(doc, 'circle')
    ])
  )
  .then(images => {
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    images.forEach((img, i) => 
      ctx.drawImage(img, i * 120, 0)
    );
  })
  .catch(console.error);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="250" height="200"></canvas>
```

---

An other method is a kind of an CSS hack, that I first read about from [Lea Verou](http://lea.verou.me/).
CSS has a [`:target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:target) selector, which allows to style only the element to which the document's hash points to.

This means you can set some rules depending on which element has been targeted from the url's `#id`.

As an example, my svg has these simple rules:

```
 rect, circle { /* always hide */
   visibility: hidden;
 }
 :target { /* show only the targeted element */
   visibility: visible;
 }
```

And now from your page all you have to do is

```js
function loadImage(url) {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    const img = new Image();
    img.onload = e => res(img);
    img.onerror = rej;
    img.src = url;
  });
}

function loadImages(urls) {
  return Promise.all(urls.map(loadImage));
}

const base = 'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/s7aynuqx6pe1we8/fake_use.svg';

loadImages([
    base + '#rect',
    base + '#circle'
  ])
  .then(images => {
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    images.forEach((img, i) =>
      ctx.drawImage(img, i * 120, 0)
    );
  })
  .catch(console.error);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="250" height="200"></canvas>
```